# Unable to save stripe payments to table

Tags: django, django-models, stripe-payments

I followed this stripe payments tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-tutorial/. I'm using the pop-up box. I'm not sure how I can save the information to the Payments table.

This is my view code. The view works, but nothing saves to the model. I'm struggling to save data from user input to my databases. Is there a good tutorial on this? I'm new to Django.

The model PremiumPurchase has all these elements.

```
class PaymentsView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'page.html'
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
         return context


from catalog.extras import generate_order_id
def charge(request): # new
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
           datetime_done = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=3)
           order_number = generate_order_id(18)
           PremiumPurchase = stripe.Charge.create(
            user = request.user, 
            token = request.POST['stripeToken'],
            description = "Purchase of Premium",
            datetime_payment = datetime.datetime.now(),
            datetime_done = datetime_done,
            order_id=order_number,
            amount=2.99,
            success=True,
        )
        PremiumPurchase.save()
    except:
        raise ValidationError("The card has been declined")

    return render(request, 'premium/charge.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember that doesn't work like that. 
You need to modify your code to something similar:

```
        c = stripe.Charge.create(
            user = request.user, 
            token = request.POST['stripeToken'],
            description = "Purchase of Premium",
            datetime_payment = datetime.datetime.now(),
            datetime_done = datetime_done,
            order_id=order_number,
            amount=2.99,
            success=True
        )


        premium_purchase = PremiumPurchase(
            # populate your model fields here
            # I don't know your model,
            # but for example it could be like this
            stripe_id=c.id,
            paid=c.paid,
            refunded=c.refunded,
            outcome=c.outcome
        )

        premium_purchase.save()
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still did not save.